# AWS with django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm just wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or is developing with AWS really hard/confusing?

Currently I have an EC2 instance with the following address:

```
ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

And with that a elastic beanstalk application environment:

```
http://XXX.XXXXXX.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/
```

I find that it's really hard/long to code something, put it on the server, and test what it looks like by going to `http://XXX.XXXXXX.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/` as what I need to do is this:

1) Upload the files via FTP to `ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

2) SSH inside to `ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` and do `eb deploy`

3) Wait 2-3 minutes for the server to deploy

4) View the changes at `http://XXX.XXXXXX.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com`

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Normally this is what I'm used to do:

1) Upload file via FTP to `http://mywebsite.com`

2) SSH inside `http://mywebsite.com`

3) Do `python manage.py runserver` or `gunicorn mySite.wsgi:application`

4) View changes at `http://mywebsite.com` without having to wat 2-3 minutes for it to deploy.

Can someone guide me on what I might be doing wrong? I'm not too sure on what I'm missing here.

Thank you!

Comment: If you find something else http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Comment: https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is. There's no need to deploy to a server to see your code running; that's why Django has a built-in development server, you can run it on your laptop. If you're complaining about the deployment process itself, then maybe you could investigate a service like Heroku that is easier to get up and running.

Answer (score 1):

With AWS Elastic Beanstalk you dont exactly "FTP" files to the server. With the EB API tools you should only `eb deploy` and your latest GIT commit will deploy all files to your EB servers.

In my case, it only takes 3-4 lines of terminal commands to get everything up and running

1. git add -A
2. git commit -m '04212016_1_east'
3. ./manage.py collectstatic (optional step since I use S3 for static files)
4. eb deploy